# Is it normal Hadoop to be 60 times slower than local computations?

Tags: hadoop, machine-learning, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I am doing machine learning tasks on hadoop (regard forward execution) cluster with dozens of nodes. In case of dataset sizes like 10k samples per 300 features, Hadoop processing (running common models like shallow neural nets or decision trees) can take up to 6 hours. Simultaneously, the same or similar task, executed on local machine in Matlab, Java or Numpy takes 10-15 minutes.

Is this normal for Hadoop or this means I do something wrong?

Comment: yup, this is within expected behavior. if you need a faster distributed programming model, look at spark, which uses dags, rather than MR

Comment: It is also normal for people to *not tune their installations*. They just install base Hadoop and expect it to be quick for some reason... How many nodes? Using YARN with what execution engine or framework? What heap sizes are set on the hadoop daemons? What container sizes are allowed? What data are you reading? Hadoop has to do more work with "small files" less than the block size, and columnar formats are easier to process than plaintext.. Etc. But yeah https://aadrake.com/command-line-tools-can-be-235x-faster-than-your-hadoop-cluster.html

Comment: obviously something is wrong, need more info what are you doing